# I have an error NetworkDispatcher.processRequest

Tags: java, android-studio

I have an error like this.
I receive data from python and put data on android.
I already checked 'para' and it had parameter, so I couldn't find wrong with this code.
Please help.

**FileUploadUtils.class**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.myapplication.DataClass.BookInfo;
import com.example.myapplication.Database.DbOpenHelper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class FileUploadUtils {

    public static void goSend(File file, Context context, View view){
        DbOpenHelper mDbOpenHelper = new DbOpenHelper(context);

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("files", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, file))
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url( "http://192.168.00.000:8080/OcrParser")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        /* RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("files", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, file))
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url( "http://192.168.00.00:8080/OcrParser")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build(); */


        // OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        //OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {


                SimpleDateFormat format =
                        new SimpleDateFormat ( "yyyy년 MM월dd일 HH시mm분ss초", Locale.KOREA);

                String time = format.format(new Date());
                String para = response.body().string();
                Log.d("Test : ", para);
                mDbOpenHelper.open();
                mDbOpenHelper.create();
                mDbOpenHelper.insertColumn(time,para, new Date().getTime());
                BookInfo.para = para;
                mDbOpenHelper.close();

            }
        });
    }



}
```

and I have log like that.

**error log**

```
E/Volley: [29105] NetworkDispatcher.processRequest: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
    at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:204)
    at com.android.volley.Request.encodeParameters(Request.java:491)
    at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:477)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:245)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:219)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:97)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:131)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:120)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)
```

I really want to solve it.
Please let me know about the problem and how to solve it.

Comment: Hi, looks like this part of the code is throwing the exception: Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url( "http://192.168.00.000:8080/OcrParser")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

Comment: Are you sure that server is able to do its job? use curl first.

Comment: Oh it's just a random number to upload here. I'm sorry about short explanation. In my code, I wrote it well.

Comment: I recommend you to create a unit test to figure out what's is going on with that call. The error is located in line 491. I don't know what is it.